# example of uncountable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking for simple proofs of uncountable sets: I know a set is said to be uncountable if there is no injective function from the set to the natural numbers. I know the set of real numbers is uncountable, open interval and the set of irrational numbers. any other easy ones that pop out to you?

Comment: The number of subsets of a countable set.

Comment: cant I map the number of each subset to the natrual numbers? first maps to 1 nth maps to n

Comment: The number of subsets of the set containing all the subsets of a countable set.

Comment: is that like the cantor set?

Comment: @PeterFranek I think you mean the number of subsets of a countably infitite set like the power set of the natural numbers?

Comment: @Faust7 Yes, that's what "countable" usually means.

Comment: @PeterFranek, actually I think most formal definitions of "countable" count finite sets as countable.  At least some (including http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set ) do.

Answer (score 2):

The set of all sequences containing only the digits $0$ or $1$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, following the above answer, there are the Cantor sets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), which allow to construct the Lebesgue functions ([Continuity of the Lebesgue function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481814/continuity-of-the-lebesgue-function)).
Another remarkable example is the Vitali sets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set)